# XML deserialization not working - there is an error in XML document (0, 0)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize an XML response but I can't seem to understand what is not working here

These are my classes (generated with the .NET developer tools)

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2007-01/calcolaIup/")]
[XmlRoot("GSSC.calcolaIupResponse", Namespace = "http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2007-01/calcolaIup/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class GSSCcalcolaIupResponse
{
    private param1 paramField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
    public param1 param
    {
        get
        {
            return this.paramField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.paramField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class param1
{
    private string iupField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string iup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.iupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.iupField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The xml response is like this:

```
<m:GSSC.calcolaIupResponse xmlns:m="http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2013-01/calcolaIup/">
    <param>
        <iup>0000W05RNF</iup>
    </param>
</m:GSSC.calcolaIupResponse>
```

And here's the code for deserialization.

```
GSSCcalcolaIupResponse iup = new GSSCcalcolaIupResponse();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GSSCcalcolaIupResponse));

IUPDummyResponse retValue = new IUPDummyResponse();

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    if (soapFault == null)
        iup = (GSSCcalcolaIupResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Have you validated that `xml` really *does* contain the text you've shown? Typically the error you've got is due to trying to deserialize an empty string.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah it does contain the exact string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace in your class `GSSCcalcolaIupResponse` and namespace in your xml string are different. It is the reason. Just change to use the same namespace, it will fix the error:

```
- http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2007-01/calcolaIup/
- http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2013-01/calcolaIup/
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it still doesn't work though. Exception: error on root element

Comment: @zombiechainsaw, I tried already. It is working. I use the namespace in xml string 'http://www.crs.lombardia.it/schemas/DCSanita/GSSC/2013-01/calcolaIup/' to replace both 2 namespaces in the class definition. Note: change both XmlType and XmlRoot